# How can I Use Access to combine tables of information

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have two tables in access with a common ID number in both. One table has mail to info and the other table has account information. The account information can have multiple listings per ID. The mail to info has one listing per ID. I need to combine the two tables to create a new table with 1 row per ID but containing multiple columns with the added account information. How do I do that?

Comment: Why you want to combine both the table in one table?

Comment: Because I need all the information to merge into a letter that is being sent to the business on the mail info table.

Comment: You can write sql query using join too get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Use the query wizard to create a new "temporary" table - a 'view' (a query). This you can use then as source for your letter.